# trying to wrap my head around indexing into a tibble of lists of tibbles

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, nested, tidyr

I want to index values out of a tbl that is made up of some regular columns and some lists of tibbles. THe basic structure is this:

```
# A tibble: 1,200 x 13
   city    country       month data               model    modelgam  glance_lm           rsq glance_gam       aic_gam tidy_lm          augment_lm         res        
   <chr>   <chr>         <dbl> <list>             <list>   <list>    <list>            <dbl> <list>             <dbl> <list>           <list>             <list>     
 1 Abidjan Côte D'Ivoire     1 <tibble [114 × 6]> <S3: lm> <S3: Gam> <tibble [1 × 11]> 0.233 <tibble [1 × 6]>   154.  <tibble [2 × 5]> <tibble [114 × 9]> <dbl [114]>
 2 Abidjan Côte D'Ivoire     2 <tibble [114 × 6]> <S3: lm> <S3: Gam> <tibble [1 × 11]> 0.342 <tibble [1 × 6]>   164.  <tibble [2 × 5]> <tibble [114 × 9]> <dbl [114]>
 3 Abidjan Côte D'Ivoire     3 <tibble [114 × 6]> <S3: lm> <S3: Gam> <tibble [1 × 11]> 0.274 <tibble [1 × 6]>   152.  <tibble [2 × 5]> <tibble [114 × 9]> <dbl [114]>
 4 Abidjan Côte D'Ivoire     4 <tibble [114 × 6]> <S3: lm> <S3: Gam> <tibble [1 × 11]> 0.376 <tibble [1 × 6]>   145.  <tibble [2 × 5]> <tibble [114 × 9]> <dbl [114]>
 5 Abidjan Côte D'Ivoire     5 <tibble [114 × 6]> <S3: lm> <S3: Gam> <tibble [1 × 11]> 0.451 <tibble [1 × 6]>   112.  <tibble [2 × 5]> <tibble [114 × 9]> <dbl [114]>
 6 Abidjan Côte D'Ivoire     6 <tibble [114 × 6]> <S3: lm> <S3: Gam> <tibble [1 × 11]> 0.419 <tibble [1 × 6]>    87.4 <tibble [2 × 5]> <tibble [114 × 9]> <dbl [114]>
 7 Abidjan Côte D'Ivoire     7 <tibble [114 × 6]> <S3: lm> <S3: Gam> <tibble [1 × 11]> 0.249 <tibble [1 × 6]>   129.  <tibble [2 × 5]> <tibble [114 × 9]> <dbl [114]>
 8 Abidjan Côte D'Ivoire     8 <tibble [114 × 6]> <S3: lm> <S3: Gam> <tibble [1 × 11]> 0.228 <tibble [1 × 6]>   153.  <tibble [2 × 5]> <tibble [114 × 9]> <dbl [114]>
 9 Abidjan Côte D'Ivoire     9 <tibble [114 × 6]> <S3: lm> <S3: Gam> <tibble [1 × 11]> 0.230 <tibble [1 × 6]>   124.  <tibble [2 × 5]> <tibble [113 × 9]> <dbl [113]>
10 Abidjan Côte D'Ivoire    10 <tibble [113 × 6]> <S3: lm> <S3: Gam> <tibble [1 × 11]> 0.292 <tibble [1 × 6]>    98.7 <tibble [2 × 5]> <tibble [113 × 9]> <dbl [113]>
# ... with 1,190 more rows
```

If I want to pull the p.value out of glance_lm for the first record (for example), I can use double brackets (since it is a list), like this:

```
> cmodels_details$glance_lm[[1]]$p.value
[1] 5.430896e-08
```

However, if I want all the p.values, this will not work:

```
> cmodels_details$glance_lm[[]]$p.value
NULL
```

In my case, I specifically want to pull the estimates for the two models out of their list and plot regression lines on a figure for each record. So being able to grab the intercepts and slopes (one record at a time) like this:

```
 cmodels_details$tidy_lm[[1]]$estimate
[1] 26.379383982  0.007833912
```

or just the intercept:

```
> cmodels_details$tidy_lm[[1]]$estimate[1]
[1] 26.37938
```

is not very helpful. Ultimately I'd like to add some ggplot code to the data structure that plots a figure for each record, but in order to make regression lines for the two models (lm and gam), I need to get the estimates out of each record's tibble (or the list of tibbles)

Here is a snip of the data I am using, and the code to get into the proper shape.

```
> dput(small_tb)
structure(list(dt = structure(c(14245, 14276, 14304, 14335, 14365, 
14396, 14426, 14457, 14488, 14518, 14549, 14579, 14610, 14641, 
14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 
14944, 14975, 15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 15126, 15156, 15187, 
15218, 15248, 15279, 15309, 15340, 15371, 15400, 15431, 15461, 
15492, 15522, 15553, 15584, 15614, 15645, 15675, 15706, 15737, 
15765, 15796, 15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 14245, 14276, 
14304, 14335, 14365, 14396, 14426, 14457, 14488, 14518, 14549, 
14579, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 
14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14975, 15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 
15126, 15156, 15187, 15218, 15248, 15279, 15309, 15340, 15371, 
15400, 15431, 15461, 15492, 15522, 15553, 15584, 15614, 15645, 
15675, 15706, 15737, 15765, 15796, 15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 
15949), class = "Date"), averagetemperature = c(-4.299, 1.454, 
4.808, 7.623, 12.627, 17.305, 19.792, 21.724, 19.502, 11.22, 
10.261, 1.563, -0.595, 0.771, 6.489, 10.935, 13.803, 19.055, 
24.106, 24.948, 19.229, 14.582, 8.539, -0.071, -1.582, 0.276, 
3.474, 7.383, 12.133, 18.011, 24.412, 23.414, 18.331, 13.837, 
9.555, 5.327, 2.67, 3.698, 12.145, 8.383, 14.956, 19.532, 25.909, 
22.778, 18.693, 12.229, 7.27, 5.592, 1.056, -0.509, 1.323, 6.644, 
13.734, 17.913, 21.914, 22.23, 19.977, -5.36, -0.372, 3.579, 
10.478, 15.447, 19.058, 21.103, 22.769, 17.043, 10.364, 8.217, 
-0.624, -2.359, -1.456, 6.715, 12.076, 17.119, 21.943, 24.789, 
22.67, 19.172, 11.911, 5.876, -2.165, -4.463, -1.244, 3.474, 
10.555, 16.917, 21.032, 24.564, 22.13, 19.301, 12.001, 8.013, 
2.987, -0.0410000000000004, 2.185, 8.734, 10.324, 17.779, 20.165, 
24.479, 22.731, 18.177, 12.436, 4.103, 2.586, -0.968, -1.365, 
2.518, 9.723, 15.544, 20.892, 24.722, 21.001, 17.408), averagetemperatureuncertainty = c(0.336, 
0.328, 0.247, 0.348, 0.396, 0.554, 0.481, 0.315, 0.225, 0.162, 
0.372, 0.348, 0.348, 0.364, 0.357, 0.538, 0.892, 0.33, 0.325, 
0.36, 0.322, 0.241, 0.307, 0.326, 0.522, 0.446, 0.279, 0.265, 
0.733, 0.773, 0.255, 0.404, 0.173, 0.154, 0.334, 0.483, 0.727, 
0.567, 0.369, 0.347, 0.835, 0.519, 0.516, 0.42, 0.329, 0.333, 
0.263, 0.537, 0.528, 0.473, 0.275, 0.462, 0.863, 0.669, 0.322, 
0.373, 1.033, 0.288, 0.214, 0.14, 0.259, 0.267, 0.452, 0.348, 
0.277, 0.22, 0.153, 0.181, 0.228, 0.314, 0.319, 0.235, 0.135, 
0.2, 0.387, 0.28, 0.257, 0.165, 0.154, 0.174, 0.436, 0.355, 0.33, 
0.167, 0.222, 0.312, 0.42, 0.438, 0.163, 0.16, 0.23, 0.298, 0.466, 
0.493, 0.253, 0.276, 0.258, 0.301, 0.39, 0.403, 0.224, 0.269, 
0.344, 0.298, 0.257, 0.29, 0.241, 0.255, 0.355, 0.281, 0.273, 
0.279, 0.323, 1.048), city = c("Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", 
"Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago", 
"New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", 
"New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", 
"New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", 
"New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", 
"New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", 
"New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", 
"New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", 
"New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", 
"New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", "New York", 
"New York", "New York", "New York"), country = c("United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", 
"United States"), latitude = c("42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", 
"42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", 
"42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", 
"42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", 
"42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", 
"42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", 
"42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", 
"42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", 
"42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "42.59N", "40.99N", "40.99N", 
"40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", 
"40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", 
"40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", 
"40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", 
"40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", 
"40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", 
"40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", 
"40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N", "40.99N"), 
    longitude = c("87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", 
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", 
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", 
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", 
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", 
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", 
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", 
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", 
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", 
    "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "87.27W", "74.56W", "74.56W", 
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", 
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", 
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", 
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", 
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", 
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", 
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", 
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", 
    "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", "74.56W", 
    "74.56W")), row.names = c(NA, -114L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(dt = structure(list(
    format = ""), class = c("collector_date", "collector")), 
    AverageTemperature = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), AverageTemperatureUncertainty = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), City = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Country = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Latitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Longitude = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
```

And some code:

```
# load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(gam)
# library(broom)
# library(purrr)

# Load the data from dput() and take a look
summary(gltd)
str(gltd)
names(gltd)

# make lowercasae
gltd <- rename_all(gltd, tolower)
names(gltd)

# nest data, 100 major cities
by_city_month <- gltd %>% 
  filter(year(dt) >= 1900) %>%
  mutate(month = month(dt)) %>%
  mutate(yr1900 = year(dt) - 1900) %>%
  group_by(city, country, month) %>%
  nest()

by_city_month

# define function for linear model
city_model_lm <- function(df) {
  lm(averagetemperature ~ yr1900, data = df)
}

# define function for GAM
city_model_gam <- function(df) {
  gam(averagetemperature ~ s(yr1900), data = df)
}

# create columns for the models
cmodels <- by_city_month %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, city_model_lm), 
         modelgam = map(data, city_model_gam)
  )

cmodels_details <- cmodels %>%
  mutate(
    glance_lm = model %>% map(glance),  #model summary: rsquared...
    rsq = glance_lm %>% map_dbl("r.squared"),  #extract rsquared

    glance_gam = modelgam %>% map(broom::glance), #GAM model summary
    aic_gam = glance_gam %>% map_dbl("AIC"), #extract AIC

    tidy_lm = model %>% map(tidy), #model estimate: coeff...

    augment_lm = model %>% map(augment), #observation stats: resid,hat...
    res = augment_lm %>% map(".resid") #extract resid
  )
```

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: `sapply(cmodels_details$glance_lm, '[[', '.pvalue')`?

Comment: Works with last term corrected to p.value.What do the '[[' do?

Comment: It extracts the list member named whatever comes after, in this case `'p.value'`. (Sorry for the typo, btw.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution that should give you what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)

cmodels_details %>%
  transmute(
    city = city,
    month = month,
    p_val = map_dbl(glance_lm, "p.value"),
    coefs = map(tidy_lm, "estimate")
  ) %>% 
  unnest(coefs) %>% 
  mutate(x = rep(c("intercept", "x1"), nrow(.) / 2))) %>% 
  spread(x, coefs)
# A tibble: 24 x 5
#   city    month  p_val intercept      x1
#   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 Chicago     1 0.0790  -156.     1.40  
# 2 Chicago     2 0.875     12.2   -0.0999
# 3 Chicago     3 0.935     20.2   -0.131 
# 4 Chicago     4 0.468     58.3   -0.451 
# 5 Chicago     5 0.411    -23.9    0.337 
# 6 Chicago     6 0.630     -0.429  0.169 
# 7 Chicago     7 0.505    -43.9    0.605 
# 8 Chicago     8 0.814     35.9   -0.116 
# 9 Chicago     9 0.872     14.6    0.0414
#10 Chicago    10 0.807    -12.2    0.228 
# ... with 14 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to the following: "Ultimately I'd like to add some ggplot code to the data structure that plots a figure for each record, but in order to make regression lines for the two models (lm and gam), I need to get the estimates out of each record's tibble (or the list of tibbles)", try [`geom_smooth()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html). You don't need to fit all the models to plot the LM and GAM models! Hope this was helpful to you!

```
by_city_month %>% unnest() %>% # your data from above
  ggplot(aes(x = yr1900, y = averagetemperature, group = interaction(city,month))) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F, color = "black", alpha = .7) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", se = F, color = "pink", alpha = .7, size = .5, linetype = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: How about more obscure methods? I can get these to work fine, but not so much with  method = survival::survreg, or by specifying a formula (which looked hopeful for a moment. Somthing like; method = 'lm', formula = averagetemperature ~ yr1900 + month.

Comment: In that case, try @DiceboyT's suggestion. The `map_dbl()` function is definitely the way to go.